# Is it possible to create a Kudu table using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, impala, kudu

I have a database in Impala, and I need to use Kudu tables in it.
I'd like to use SQLAlchemy in my Python code to interact with the database.
Although Impala is not a supported dialect in SQLALchemy, I have been able to access data and do basic modifications in my existing Kudu and non-Kudu tables.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582842/impala-connection-via-sqlalchemy) question and its answers and also the GitHub page linked there, but they are about connecting to an Impala db, which I managed to do.

(I have also considered using the [Kudu Python Client](https://docs.cloudera.com/runtime/7.2.0/kudu-development/topics/kudu-python-client.html) instead of SQLAlchemy, but that doesn't work because my code will run on Ubuntu 18.04 and it is [not supported](https://kudu.apache.org/releases/1.8.0/docs/installation.html#install_packages).)

My question is specifically about the creation of Kudu tables using SQLAlchemy.
When I use plain SQL, it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    id INT,
    message STRING,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
  )
  STORED AS KUDU
```

There are two things that indicate that this is a Kudu table: the presence of a primary key, which doesn't exist in Impala, and of course the last row.

Marking a column as primary key is not a problem in SQLAlchemy. But is there a way to include `STORED AS KUDU` in a table creation call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Kudu support exists but is buggy (as of 2021 Oct 1)

First: Impala dialect of SQLAlchemy **is** implemented, but in the impyla package.

Impyla is supposed to support Kudu as well, see [this issue](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/issues/259) and the commit related to it. However, starting from release `0.17a8`, support for primary key constrains was omitted from the package, which crippled the Kudu support as Kudu tables need to have at least one primary key.

So to answer the question, creating Kudu tables is possible using `impyla 0.17a7`, but not with any later releases - again, as of October 2021. I filed [this](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/issues/476) issue about the matter.

### Feature usage

Kudu support was implemented by adding two keyword arguments to the `Table()` constructor, namely `impala_stored_as` and `impala_partition_by`. Usage is obvious when taking the imperative approach and calling `Table()` directly. However, the arguments can easily be passed with the declarative approach too, using `__table_args__` (which also works with mixins).

For an explanation of the imperative and declarative mappings see [this page](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_styles.html) of the SQLAlchemy documentation.
For working examples, see the next section.

### Examples

An imperative example, taken from [here](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/issues/259), but with fixed parameter name and primary key:

```py
>>> import sqlalchemy
>>> engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('impala://node-1.cluster')
>>> table = sqlalchemy.Table('sweet_new_table', sqlalchemy.MetaData(), sqlalchemy.Column('id', sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True), impala_stored_as='KUDU')
>>> print(str(sqlalchemy.schema.CreateTable(table, bind=engine)))

CREATE TABLE sweet_new_table (
    id INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
STORED AS KUDU
```

My working solution for a declarative (ORM) example:

```py
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String

Base = declarative_base()

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "my_table_name"
    __table_args__ = {"impala_stored_as": "KUDU"}

    id = Column(String, primary_key=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("impala://node-1.cluster")
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```